# Send auto email if customer chose definite payment method

Tags: email, ce-1.8.1.0, payment-methods

I want to bring to the store a new payment method - lets call it payment2, but the new system after paying customer (redirect to third party site) and returned to the store not generated automatically email order. 
I think about to do that - every order with payment2 will automatically sends your email (no matter whether the payment will be OK or not), i find line in file that normaly send email in:

app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Model\Type\Onepage.php

```
  /**
                 * a flag to set that there will be redirect to third party after confirmation
                 * eg: paypal standard ipn
                 */
                $redirectUrl = $this->getQuote()->getPayment()->getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl();
                /**
                 * we only want to send to customer about new order when there is no redirect to third party
                 */
                if (!$redirectUrl && $order->getCanSendNewEmailFlag()) {
                    try {
                        $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        Mage::logException($e);
                    }
                }
```

Of course i copy that to app\code\local... now i wanna change line

```
 if (!$redirectUrl && $order->getCanSendNewEmailFlag()) {
```

To

```
  if ((!$redirectUrl && $order->getCanSendNewEmailFlag()) || ($order->getPayment()->getMethod() != 'name of payment2')) {
```

but it doesn't work ;/

PS I cannot write only
 `if ($order->getCanSendNewEmailFlag()) {` 
bcs I have another payment method that send email if payemnt is OK, but dont send it otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use

`$order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()` instead of `$order->getPayment()->getMethod()`.it is give you payment method code.

Just like Cash on delivery payment method code  is  `cashondelivery`

Comment: Your code works ;) I also change != to ==